# 400 bad request (making game with node and socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Making a game, **I have no idea what I am doing** when it comes to the online aspect.

I am using node.js using my computer as the server host and client (localhost:3000)

```
var express = require('express'); //no idea what I am doing here
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var socket = require("socket.io");
var io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);
app.use(express.static("public"));

console.log("server is up"); //tells me that the server is ready

function newConnection(socket) {
    console.log("new player!", socket.id); //tells me when a new player connects.
}
```

also have this code within the main public javascript file

```
var socket;
socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");
```

Whenever a new player  connects i get 400 bad request errors and the game thinks multiple players have joined.

[picture to aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC7S0.jpg)

so pls help.

Comment: Try following the [tutorial for socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/). I recently created a multiplayer drawing game using websockets and found it exceedingly confusing to figure out how websockets work; there's simply no clear tutorials. That tutorial didn't help me because I wasn't using `socket.io` but maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my game, I had a constructor function called "Number" and that was causing the problem the entire time.

I'm assuming that the socket.io or node.js already had a function called "Number" and that's what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to handle what happens when someone connects to your server.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
server.listen(3000)  //server listens on port 3000
var io = require("socket.io")(server)

//this will be called when a new client connects
io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
   //socket is the socket object of the new client
   console.log("new socket connected with socket id = " + socket.id)

})
```

Look at socket.io docs for more info.

Comment: so are you saying that not doing anything but console logging is causing these errors?

Comment: nvm I figured it out, a function in my game had a name identical to another function in socket.io "Number" and that's what was causing the problem.